# Can't access the magento2.1.7 dashboard properly

Tags: magento2

After the installation of magento 2.1.7 i can't access my dashboard properly and it was not responding.In the place of magento fevicon symbol it displays xampp symbol.[image]

Comment: hi @satish may i know still whether you facing the same problem (admin content)?

Answer (score 1):

Open up app/etc/di.xml find the path `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink` and replace it with `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

After that remove below directories:

1. Remove `var/cache`
2. Remove `var/composer_home`
3. Remove `var/generation`
4. Remove `var/page_cache`
5. Remove `var/view_preprocessed`
6. run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

[image]
Hope this help!!!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now it is working fine.but fevicon symbol not changed. I have done first 5 things  but I didn't understand  run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Which OS you are working on the Windows or Unbantu?

Comment: iam using windows 10

Comment: Ok run the command line for `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
`: below open the command prompt and see the screenshot in the updated answer.

Comment: Have you run the command or need more help?

Comment: I run the command successfully but can't find any changes

Comment: your main concern is favicon symbol?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60698/discussion-between-nukala-satish-and-magedev0688).